# Subscript in `siunitx` fraction mode

Tags: siunitx, subscripts

I would like to automate my SI Units a bit. Unfortunately I'm not getting the desired result if I add subscript text. I tried multiple versions with `\text` and similiar functions. How can I display a fraction with subscripts with `siunitx`?

```latex
\documentclass[
    fontsize=12pt,
    paper=a4,
    oneside,
    leqno
    ]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[
    fleqn   
    ]{amsmath}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    locale = DE,
    per-mode=fraction,
    quotient-mode=fraction,
    fraction-function=\tfrac
}


\NewDocumentCommand\DeclareNewQuantity{mmm}{%
    \DeclareSIUnit{#2}{#3}%
    \DeclareDocumentCommand{#1}{O{}m}{\SI[##1]{##2}{#2}}%
}

\DeclareNewQuantity
    \DoesWhatIWant
    \doesWhatIWant
    {\kg\per\kg}
\DeclareNewQuantity
    \DoesNotWhatIWant
    \doesNotWhatIWant
    {\kg_{H2}\per\kg_{FeTi}}

\begin{document}

$\DoesWhatIWant{1,2345}$

$\DoesNotWhatIWant{1,2345}$

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

The second should look like the first output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decalre `\kg_{H2}` and `\kg_{FeTi}` as new units with `\DeclareSIUnit` first.

```
\DeclareSIUnit\kgh{\kg_{H2}}
\DeclareSIUnit\kgfe{\kg_{FeTi}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=12pt,
    paper=a4,
    oneside,
    leqno
    ]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[
    fleqn   
    ]{amsmath}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    locale = DE,
    per-mode=fraction,
    quotient-mode=fraction,
    fraction-function=\tfrac
}

\DeclareSIUnit\kgh{\kg_{H2}}
\DeclareSIUnit\kgfe{\kg_{FeTi}}

\NewDocumentCommand\DeclareNewQuantity{mmm}{%
    \DeclareSIUnit{#2}{#3}%
    \DeclareDocumentCommand{#1}{O{}m}{\SI[##1]{##2}{#2}}%
}

\DeclareNewQuantity
    \DoesWhatIWant
    \doesWhatIWant
    {\kg\per\kg}
\DeclareNewQuantity
    \DoesNotWhatIWant
    \doesNotWhatIWant
    {\kgh\per\kgfe}

\begin{document}

$\DoesWhatIWant{1,2345}$

$\DoesNotWhatIWant{1,2345}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect :) Thank you!

Comment: Very ugly this answer wih 0 score. My sincere compliments.